# Vertically Animate DOM Element with "align-self-center" Bootstrap Parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-animations, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to vertically animate a DOM element such as `animation-test` within a certain bounds while its parent elements maintain vertically centered relative to the body of the document? The inclusion of the Bootstrap class `align-self-center` in `animation-test-parent` seems to prevent this from being possible.

For more context, I'm seeking to implement an animation similar to one on mobile Chrome, attached below while maintaining the vertical alignment of my content: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgKJ.jpg

If the above isn't possible, how would you suggest implementing this UI?

Many thanks!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#animation-test {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    line-height: 280px;
  }
  /*  100% {line-height: 100px;}*/
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    line-height: 280px;
  }
  /*  100% {line-height: 100px;}*/
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    line-height: 280px;
  }
  /*  100% {line-height: 100px;}*/
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    line-height: 280px;
  }
  /*  100% {line-height: 100px;}*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="MDB-Free/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div class="container px-0 h-100">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
      <div class="col align-self-center">
        <div id="animation-test-parent" class="row no-gutters">
          <div id="animation-test" class="col">
            animation debug
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<div class="row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="col align-self-center">
        <div id="animation-test-parent" class="row no-gutters">
            <div id="animation-test" class="col azk-title">
                animation debug
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#animation-test {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s;
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
-o-animation: fadein 2s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {line-height: 280px;}
}
```